# Rails 3 regular expression. like in query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, sql-like

I want to query my database table where the age field have a value 24 or 26.
I tried using 'like' in my query.

```
User.where('age like ? or age like ?',"%24%","%26%")
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: why are you using like when you can direclty check for equality? User.where("age = ? or age = ?", 24, 26)

Comment: your query should be working, what us the error you are getting ?!

Comment: How about User.find_by_age([24,26])  ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
User.where("age in ?",["24","26"])
```

Let consdier your age in string with comma delimiter

```
ages = "24,26,28,17,18"
age_array = ages.split(",")
User.where("age in ?",age_array)
```

Comment: I believe @polurupraveen is looking one with LIKE

Comment: @sameera207 but he doesnt have to when he is only checking for exact number, right?

Comment: That will match the field values exactly. I want to query using a regular expression because my user age is a string with commas as delimiter

Comment: @polurupraveen then you can try converting the string to int

Comment: @JohnnyB-- Ages are comma separated in the database. Not in a variable

Comment: @polurupraveen I just give an example ages varaible value can be assigned from database column too.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble guys. My query was correct except for an extra comma when i tried in my console. My bad. Thanks for helping and sorry again

Comment: `User.where("age in ?",["24","26"])` will give you syntax error you have to use `User.where("age in (?)",["24","26"])` note for `()` surrounding the `?`

Comment: @polurupraveen Please delete the question if it was just a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too ..

```
User.where(:age => age_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern for multiple search attributes:

```
ages = ["24", "26"]
query = ages.map { |age| "age like '%#{age}%'" }.join(" OR ")
User.where(query)
```

It will auto generate a query like this:

```
SELECT 'users.*' FROM 'users' WHERE (age like '%24%' OR age like '%26%')
```

Hope this solution will help you!